# How to send a dynamic list as a response to FastAPI?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I have a Python module that generates a list of users, and your otps (one-time password):

```
my_dynamic_list = [{"username": "user1", "otp": "12345"},{"username": "user1", "otp": "12345"}]
```

In the same project, I want to provide an endpoint to return all these users, reading `my_dynamic_list` in memory.

```
@app.get("/otp/users")
def get_runtime_clients():
    return Response(content=my_dynamic_list, media_type="application/json")
```

I was try some ways but nothing returning all users in the endpoint.

How can I do that?

Comment: Just `return my_dynamic_list` should work just fine. There is no need to specify the content type or return a `Response` explicitly, FastAPI will handle that for you. If you want to document the return value properly for the built-in docs generation, create a Pydantic model that matches the expected format and either add type information for the return value of your controller function, or use `response_model` on your `@app.get` decorator. If that doesn't work as expected, add working code that shows the complete problem and _what_ you expected the result to be.